Return statement error during compilation , without using try catch method
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static Void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}    

Here is a basic code that I was trying to compile on an online compiler. It throws me a return statement error. Though I've added a return statement after the for loop – return i; – it showed me:
./Main.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
       return i ;
              ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class Main


Does this answer your question? Scope of Variable in While vs. For Loop

It's public static void, not public static Void

What do you mean? If the method is void, no return statement is necessary -> no compilation error

Sorry, I misread the question

Because I misread the question. You didn't do anything wrong. Again, I'm sorry.
